# Tensorflow setup on RStudio/ R | CentOS

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, centos7

For the last 5 days, I am trying to make Keras/Tensorflow packages work in R. I am using RStudio for installation and have used `conda`, `miniconda`, `virtualenv` but it crashes each time in the end. Installing a library should not be a nightmare especially when we are talking about R (*one of the best statistical languages*) and TensorFlow (*one of the best deep learning libraries*). Can someone share a reliable way to install Keras/Tensorflow on CentOS 7?

Following are the steps I am using to install `tensorflow` in RStudio.

Since RStudio simply crashes each time I run `tensorflow::tf_config()` I have no way to check what is going wrong.

[image]

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") # This package also installs tensorflow
library(reticulate)
reticulate::install_miniconda()
reticulate::use_miniconda("r-reticulate")
library(tensorflow)
tensorflow::tf_config() **# Crashes at this point**

sessionInfo()


R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tensorflow_2.7.0.9000 keras_2.7.0.9000      reticulate_1.22-9000 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7      lattice_0.20-45 png_0.1-7       zeallot_0.1.0  
 [5] rappdirs_0.3.3  grid_3.6.0      R6_2.5.1        jsonlite_1.7.2 
 [9] magrittr_2.0.1  tfruns_1.5.0    rlang_0.4.12    whisker_0.4    
[13] Matrix_1.3-4    generics_0.1.1  tools_3.6.0     compiler_3.6.0 
[17] base64enc_0.1-3
```

**Update 1**
The only way RStudio does not crash while installing tensorflow is by executing following steps -

First, I created a new virtual environment using conda

```
conda create --name py38 python=3.8.0
conda activate py38
conda install tensorflow=2.4
```

Then from within RStudio, I installed reticulate and activated the virtual environment which I earlier created using conda

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
library(reticulate)
reticulate::use_condaenv("/root/.conda/envs/py38", required = TRUE)
reticulate::use_python("/root/.conda/envs/py38/bin/python3.8", required = TRUE)
reticulate::py_available(initialize = TRUE)
ts <- reticulate::import("tensorflow")
```

As soon as I try to import `tensorflow` in RStudio, it loads the library `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` instead of `/root/.conda/envs/py38/lib/libstdc++.so.6` and I get the following error -

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 39, in _import_hook
    module = _import(
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /root/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Here is what inside `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`

```
> strings /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC

GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

To resolve the library issue, I added the path of the correct `libstdc++.so.6` library having `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` in RStudio.

```
system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/.conda/envs/py38/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

and, also

```
Sys.setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "/root/.conda/envs/py38/lib")
```

But still I get the same error `` ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' ``. Somehow RStudio still loads `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` first instead of `/root/.conda/envs/py38/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

Instead of `RStudio`, if I execute the above steps in the `R` console, then also I get the exact same error.

**Update 2:**
A solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70798023/11939840)

Comment: Just one thing that stands out a bit: why are you using such an old R version? Meanwhile we're having 4.1.2.

Comment: The official version of R available on CentOS 7 is 3.6.

Comment: Have you tried to install the old versions? `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/keras/keras_2.2.5.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")` and  `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/reticulate/reticulate_1.14.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`. I had similar problems with magrittr and could only solve it with installing an archived version.

Comment: What do you mean by 'crash'? RStudio shuts down? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Why R??????????

Comment: @Saurabh What is your machine setup, what CPU, memory, and GPU are you using? Are you running in a hypervisor, via Windows WSL, or natively?

Comment: I have 8 CPUs, 32GB RAM VPS running on CentOS natively.

Comment: @Saurabh I am more interested in the GPU config, that is usually where the problems occur with TensorFlow set up in my experience.

Comment: My VPS server does not have any GPU, only 8 CPUs. It is a VPS server.

Comment: Here is a similar issue on macOS: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/723 . The solution in that case was a clean install of reticulate and Rcpp. Perhaps it would be worth updating your question with a full stack trace (e.g. per https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/13/debugging-with-lldb/)

Comment: Have you considered cross posting [here](https://community.rstudio.com/c/ml/15) or [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues) so that the RStudio staff get's notified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update on 29 July, 2022**
After months of solving this problem, I feel so stupid to have wasted time coding R on CentOS. The most popular and stable OS to code R is Ubuntu. By default, CentOS supports only the 3.6 version of R while the most stable current version of R is 4.2. With the default 3.6 version of R on CentOS, most of the libraries are outdated and they conflict with other libraries which are updated for R 4.2+. From my experience, you are going to avoid a lot of misery and frustration if you start coding R on Ubuntu. I am not sponsoring Ubuntu, the above statement is just from my experience and others might have different experiences.

**Original Answer**
Took me more than 15 days and I finally solved this problem.

Boot up a clean CentOS 7 VM, install R and dependencies (taken from Jared's answer) -

```
yum install epel-release
yum install R
yum install libxml2-devel
yum install openssl-devel
yum install libcurl-devel
yum install libXcomposite libXcursor libXi libXtst libXrandr alsa-lib mesa-libEGL libXdamage mesa-libGL libXScrnSaver
```

Now, create a conda environment

```
yum install conda
conda clean -a     # Clean cache and remove old packages, if you already have conda installed
# Install all the packages together and let conda handle versioning. It is important to give a Python version while setting up the environment. Since Tensorflow supports python 3.9.0, I have used this version 
conda create -y -n "tf" python=3.9.0 ipython tensorflow keras r-essentials r-reticulate r-tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Open a new port (`7878` or choose any port number you want) on the server to access RStudio with new `conda` environment libraries

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7878 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

then launch RStudio as follows -

```
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver \
   --server-daemonize=0 \
   --www-port 7878 \
   --rsession-which-r=$(which R) \
   --rsession-ld-library-path=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib
```

You will have your earlier environment intact on default port `8787` and a new environment with Tensorflow and Keras on `7878`.

The following code now works fine in RStudio

```
install.packages("reticulate")
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(reticulate)
library(tensorflow)
ts <- reticulate::import("tensorflow")
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps my failed attempts will help someone else solve this problem; my approach:

- boot up a clean CentOS 7 vm
- install R and some dependencies

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install R
sudo yum install libxml2-devel
sudo yum install openssl-devel
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
sudo yum install libXcomposite libXcursor libXi libXtst libXrandr alsa-lib mesa-libEGL libXdamage mesa-libGL libXScrnSaver
```

- Download and install Anaconda via linux installer script
- Create a new conda env

```
conda init
conda create --name tf
conda activate tf
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

**From within this conda env you can import tensorflow in python without error; now to access tf via R

- install an updated gcc via devtoolset

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-gcc*
```

- attempt to use tensorflow in R via the reticulate package

```
scl enable devtoolset-7 R
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github('rstudio/reticulate')
reticulate::use_condaenv("tf", conda = "~/anaconda3/bin/conda")
reticulate::repl_python()
# This works as expected but the command "import tensorflow" crashes R
# Error: *** caught segfault *** address 0xf8, cause 'memory not mapped'

# Also tried:
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github('rstudio/tensorflow')
devtools::install_github('rstudio/keras')
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow() # "successful"
tensorflow::tf_config()
# Error: *** caught segfault *** address 0xf8, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

- try older versions of tensorflow/keras

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/tensorflow@v2.4.0')
devtools::install_github('rstudio/keras@v2.4.0')
library(tensorflow)
tf_config()
# Error: *** caught segfault *** address 0xf8, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

- Try an updated version of R (v4.0)

```
# deactivate conda
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm 
export R_VERSION=4.0.0
curl -O https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/centos-7/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm

scl enable devtoolset-7 /opt/R/4.0.0/bin/R
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github('rstudio/reticulate')
reticulate::use_condaenv("tf", conda = "~/anaconda3/bin/conda")
reticulate::repl_python()
# 'import tensorflow' resulted in "core dumped"
```

I guess the issue is with R/CentOS, as you can import and use tensorflow via python normally, but I'm not sure what else to try.

I would also like to say that I had no issues with Ubuntu (which is specifically supported by tensorflow, along with macOS and Windows), and I came across these docs that might be some help: https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/display/ITH/Installing+TensorFlow+using+anaconda / https://wiki.hpcc.msu.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22709999

Comment: thanks. I really appreciate your effort in trying to solve this problem.