# Could not install tensorflow in RStudio

Tags: python, r, linux, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in R Studio through Linux terminal, by following the three methods mentioned in this link https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/, namely "auto", "virtualenv" and "conda". However, none of them worked.

Following the method "auto", we tried with the command

```
tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
```

However, it gave an error related to the tensorflow version and I haev tried with different versions of it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nKfU.png):

```
> tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
Activated conda python: /root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.*
Error: Error installing package(s): "'tensorflow==2.11.*'"
```

Then, following the "virtualenv" method, it retrieved the same error as the "auto" technique. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZUpe.png):

```
> library(reticulate)
> virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = "/usr/bin/python3")
virtualenv: r-reticulate
> virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = "/usr/bin/python3")
virtualenv: r-reticulate
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")
Using virtual environment 'r-reticulate' ...
Collecting tensorflow==2.11.*
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.* (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.*
Error: Error installing package(s): "'tensorflow==2.11.*'"
```

Finally, I tried the "conda" alternative, `conda_create("r-reticulate")`, but it gave the same error as trying with the "auto" method:

```
> install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")
Using virtual environment 'r-reticulate' ...
Collecting tensorflow==2.11.*
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.* (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.*
Error: Error installing package(s): "'tensorflow==2.11.*'"
```

Moreover, I tried following the steps on this link [Tensorflow setup on RStudio/ R | CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645074/tensorflow-setup-on-rstudio-r-centos) but we could not install the tensorflow on the new port.

For your information, there are two Python versions installed in the Linux OS, which are 3.6.8 and 2.7.5. The R Studio version is 4.1.3.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I will post the code itself.